# How do I let datatable headers adjust with the column width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables for a project and I have the following issue:

On first load, the columns of the header and data rows are nicely aligned. However, when the window is resized, the body cells shrink or grow, whereas the header cells remain a constant width. The result is a mis-alignment of the header and body rows.
The following code is used to initialize the datatable:

```
$el.DataTable({
    paging: true,
    lengthChange: true,
    searching: true,
    ordering: true,
    info: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    pageLength: 25,
    columns: getColumns(configurationObject),
    scrollX: true,
    language: localizationObject,
    data: getDataset(configurationObject),
    dom: 'lrtip',
    lengthMenu: [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, localizationObject['allRows']]
    ]
});
```

And the html is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In my quest to solve this issue, I have tried the following:

- Set `autoWidth` to true/false
- Enable/Disable the responsive plugin

Many answers revolve around the table being constructed before the dom is finished loading, or inside a hidden div preventing widths to be calculated. Neither of those are true for me. The code above gets called in a `$(document).ready(function () {}}` and is not hidden when called (as I said, initial load works fine, but I thought it is worth mentioning).

In my investigation, I noticed that, for the header row, an entirely new html table is created. The cells of that row are also given a fixed width. That does explain the misalignment to me, but, I am no closer to actually resolving the issue at hand.

I am trying to achieve either of two scenarios:

- The columns of the body are of fixed width, and horizontal scroll will take over if the table overflows. I have set `scrollX` to true, and on small screens this works very well.
- The columns of the header row are not of fixed width, but rather the width of the body columns.

Hopefully I have provided enough information for someone to find an answer, because I have googled and looked and I can't find it. If more information is needed, then please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I ran into something similar and I have to call the DataTable.adjust() every time. May be you can try it

Comment: Are you able to made a snippet example with the basic code that generate the issue?

Comment: try `<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;">`